# Making two lists which share part of its name, while its name is also an element of the list

Tags: list-manipulation

I am stalled with the following problem: I want two lists, for example:

```
name={1,2,3}
```

and

```
namec={{1,2,3},{x,y,z},name}
```

The list "namec" is a list with extra information for internal use in a (non-comercial) package, while the List "name" is a vector shown to the user. The "name" inside the list has

```
Head[name]=String
```

I tried the following piece of code:

```
 g = {1, 2, 3};
 c = {x, y, z};
 (ToExpression["Set[" <> # <> "c" <> ", {g,c," <> # <> "}]"]; 
 ToExpression["Set[" <> # <> ", g]"]) &["name"];
```

the problem is that with the second assignment, the full list "name" replace the string "name" in the list "namec" (I know it could be a little confusing, this is counterintuitive to me). With the code above I get:

```
 name={1,2,3}
```

and

```
 namec={{1,2,3},{x,y,z},{1,2,3}}
```

Without the second assignment in the piece of code shown above, I get the list "namec" I want, however, the problem appears when I added the second assignment (name=g). Actually "name" is obtained interactively with an Input, but I simplified the code here.
How can I solve this problem?, I suspect that I must use the Hold attribute but what I tried didn't work. Can somebody help me ?

Just for reference the real piece of code is:

```
With[{symbol = Input["enter a new name"]},
nom = ToString[symbol];
ToExpression[
"Set[" <> ToString[symbol] <> "c" <> ", {g,c," <> 
ToString[symbol] <> "}]"];
ToExpression["Set[" <> ToString[symbol] <> ", g]"];
```

(* finally I get the solution based on a suggestion of george2079 (I only modified the last line of his solution) :*)

```
In[68]:= name = InputString["enter symbol name"]
ToExpression[name <> "={1,2,3}"]
ToExpression[name <> "c" <> "={{1,2,3},{x,y,z},name}"]

Out[68]= "ju"

Out[69]= {1, 2, 3}

Out[70]= {{1, 2, 3}, {x, y, z}, "ju"}

In[71]:= ju

Out[71]= {1, 2, 3}

In[72]:= juc

Out[72]= {{1, 2, 3}, {x, y, z}, "ju"}
```

Comment: I don't know how to prevent the evaluation of a Symbol entered in an `Input[]` dialog.  Would it be acceptable to enter it in quotes i.e. `"name"`, or use an `InputField`?

Comment: Mr.Wizard, sorry for the delay, I just came back. An InputField is more appropriate, since it must be a name given by the user.

Comment: Mr Wizard, entering the names in quotes with InputField or Input can be equally acceptable.

Comment: I'm sorry, I am out of time today to work on this but if someone doesn't do it first I'll do my best to give you a solution tomorrow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe do this..:

```
name = {1, 2, 3};
namec = {{1, 2,3}, {x, y,z}, ToString@Unevaluated@name}

(*{{1,2, 3}, {x, y,z}, "name"}*)
```

or simply

```
namec = {{1, 3}, {x, y}, "name"}
```

Then when you want to access it..

```
Symbol@Last@namec

(*{1, 2, 3}*)
```

Edit: use input string..

```
name = InputString["enter symbol name"]
ToExpression[name <> "={1,2,3}"]
namec = {{1, 2, 3}, {x, y, z}, name}
Symbol@Last@namec
```

(*{1, 2, 3}*)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard: Thank you. What I want to do is a little more complicated, in this way I cannot use your suggestion, I modified the code shown above accordingly but it didn`t work. I'll try to specify better my question

Comment: george2079: thank you, the "name" assignment is passed interactively, I edited my question above. So, I cannot use simple lists constructions.

Comment: @Gluoncito Try using InputString[] instead..

Comment: (at)george: It don't work, if I enter say "ve", when I input "vec" I do not recover the list namec defined above. However, thank you for responding.

Comment: (at)george: it worked with a slight modification, I'll paste the solution below the question and give you the credit. Thank you.